# Right click with xf86-input-mtrack on macbook pro 13" retina

Tags: macintosh

OK So I've just installed xf86-input-mtrack on my 13" Macbook pro retina running ubuntu gnome. I copied someone's suggested settings, so my 50-synaptics.conf input section looks like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchOS "Linux"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
    Option "Ignore" "on"
    Driver          "mtrack"
    Option          "Sensitivity" "0.95"
    Option          "FingerHigh" "12"
    Option          "FingerLow" "1"
    Option          "IgnoreThumb" "true"
    Option          "IgnorePalm" "true"
    Option          "TapButton1" "0"
    Option          "TapButton2" "0"
    Option          "TapButton3" "0"
    Option          "TapButton4" "0"
    Option          "ClickFinger1" "1"
    Option          "ClickFinger2" "3"
    Option          "ClickFinger3" "3"
    Option          "ButtonMoveEmulate" "false"
    Option          "ButtonIntegrated" "true"
    Option          "ClickTime" "25"
    Option          "BottomEdge" "25"
    Option          "SwipeLeftButton" "8"
    Option          "SwipeRightButton" "9"
    Option          "SwipeUpButton" "0"
    Option          "SwipeDownButton" "0"
    Option          "ScrollDistance" "75"
    Option          "ScrollUpButton" "5"
    Option          "ScrollDownButton" "4"
EndSection
```

Now I can right-click with a sort of two-finger click, but what I really want is to be able to right-click with one finger by using the bottom right hand corner of the track pad (as it works natively on Mac OS; the trackpad can distinguish the area you click on). Is there a way to do this with xf86-input-mtrack?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work with : https://github.com/BlueDragonX/xf86-input-mtrack/issues/81#issuecomment-129102607 but only with two-finger click :|

Comment: Welcome to [Unix.SE]!  Please visit the [Help Center](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for tips on writing good answers.  In this case, for example, it would be great to provide additional information about your solution directly in your answer, rather than simply linking to a third-party site.

Comment: the settings I listed give you something like two finger click, but I'm specifically looking for a regular one finger click in the bottom right of the trackpad. If you have a macbook, you'll know what I mean.